# How to connect Tornado and Pika with RabbitMQ via a shared event loop?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, tornado, pika

I'm using the TornadoConnection adapter in Pika, however found the documentation to be light. I'd like:

1. Tornado initiates a Pika producer via a handler
2. Pika executes the consumer(s)
3. Tornado is notified via callback when the consumption is complete and updates the web client

The docs show how to use the Tornado IOLoop but I haven't seen such examples. Much appreciated.

---

Answer (score 2):

I suggest reading this blog post, it's really good:

http://reminiscential.wordpress.com/2012/04/07/realtime-notification-delivery-using-rabbitmq-tornado-and-websocket/